# Reload CollectionView with different cells

Tags: swift, api, uicollectionview

I'm a beginner in swift and want to create my first apps. In the app I use collectionViews because I follow the advise from Lets build that App on Youtube.
In my App I want to have a vertical collectionView. In this collectionView I want another collectionView that consists of 2 different cells: 1x TitleCell and ?x ContentCell.
For these cells an API-Request is send to set their values. After the API-Call is done I reload the collectionView with:

```
  self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Unfortunately when I reload the data my TitleCell gets overwritten by the ContentCell. As I have read in the swift docs about reloadData(): when its called it erases each cell and replaces it with the last called cell: In my case the ContentCell.

Therefore my question is, is there are way to reload the TitleCell and ContentCell in a way that they don't get overwritten?
And also: is it a bad practice to make a collectionView with 2 different cells?

**Here is my Code:**

API:

```
class ApiService: NSObject {
 static let sharedInstance = ApiService()

 var contentBaseUrl = "netAddress"

  func fetchContent(from url: String, completion: @escaping ([ContentModel]) -> ()) {
    fetchFeedForUrlString(urlString: "\(contentBaseUrl)/"folder"/\(url)", completion: completion)
 }

 func fetchFeedForUrlString<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(json)
            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
 }
}
```

CollectionView that calls api:

```
class VHomeCell: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var firstCell = true
var content: [ContentModel]?

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    fetchVideos()
    collectionView.register(HomeContentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ContentCellID")
    collectionView.register(LeagueCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TitleCellID")
}

//Method that causes the "error"
func fetchMatches() {

    ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchData(from: "ApiNetworkAddress", completion: { (content: [ContentModel]) in
        self.content = content
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return content?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if firstCell {
        firstCell = false
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TitleCellID", for: indexPath) as! TitleCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCellID", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell
        cell.match = matches?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 50)
}
```

ContentCell and TitleCell are just 2 UICollectionView Cells with different content in them:

```
 class TitleCell: BaseCell {
   var content: ContentModel? {
      didSet {
        title.text = content.titleText
     }
  }
 }

 class ContentCell: BaseCell {
   var content: ContentModel? {
      didSet {
         content.Text = content.text
     }
  }
 }
```

Here is the used BaseCell:

```
class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
  }

func setupViews() {

}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

I'm aware my code needs a lot of cleaning and stuff. Therefore, I'm happy if some could also point out how I can clean my code or make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using this `firstCell` property to determine which cell to configure in your `cellForItemAt` method. You should instead be using the `indexPath` parameter that's passed into the method to determine if the method is being called for the first cell or not. You can do this by checking the `indexPath`'s `item` (you can ignore the `indexPath`'s `section` since it seems you only have one section in your collection view).

So, remove the `firstCell` property altogether. Then just replace this `if` condition:

```swift
if firstCell {
```

with:

```swift
if indexPath.item == 0 {
```

To answer your other question: no, it is not bad practice to have more than one cell type per collection view.